# What am I doing wrong? (C++ arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays

so, i'm doing online challenge and this is what i have to do:
i have to output number "N" of magics. After that you input "N" amount of spells to form the magic.

So basically, an example input is:

```
5
3
2
1
1
0
```

The output of this should be 2, because 3+2=5 for the magic. HOWEVER, important note (which I'm having problems with is that each spell has +1 to the value)

Example:

```
12
5
5
4
4
4
3
3
3
2
2
2
1
```

So, 5+5=10 , but since each spell has +1 value, 6+6=12. So output should be 2.

Here is my code, but for some reason it outputs 3.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int n,c=0,br=0;
    cin>>n;
    int a[150];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        a[i]+=1;
        while(c<=n)
        {
            c+=a[i];
            br++;
        }
    }


    if(a[0]==n-1)
    br--;

    cout << br << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: title says "C arrays", but you're using C++? No idea what you mean by 'spell value', either.

Comment: Please describe the desired output in a more abstract way.

Comment: It's C++, I don't know why it says C.. the output is how many spells you need to form the main magic. For example, if N=24, you need 24 spells to form that magic. We input N (the power of magic) and then we input N amount of spells sorted by highest to lowest power. After that, we output how many spells we will need to make the magic. HOWEVER, keep in mind that EACH SPELL has +1 value to it, if the spell is 11, we'll consider it as 12.

Comment: What kind of sorcery is that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using psychic debugging skills:

```
while(c<=n)
```

Means while the total of the spells is less than or equal to the number of spells.

Which means, it uses the first 5 spell, (total is 6), then the second five spell (total is 12), and then since that's still less or equal to the number of spells (12), it uses the first four spell (total is now 16).  I think you wanted `c<n` there instead of `c<=n`.

Unrelated: your question is terribly worded and makes almost no sense.

Comment: Damn, I don't know how I missed that... thanks for your help. I'm sorry about the wrongly worded text, I was just pissed because I've been trying to do this for a while now... thanks again!

Comment: You missed that because you didn't step in with a debugger nor use even the most primitive or basic of debugging methods.  use `cout` or `printf`, and step into the code with a debugger.